# Concern with the use of dynamic sequences in ESB 4.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

In a scenario where I monitoring my proxy services in ESB 4.5.0 using BAM 2.0.1 with WSO2 products, how I can define that the dynamic endpoints and sequences used in this proxy services have their statistic enable?. So I can see their statistics in BAM.

I can anable sequences statistics in the defined sequences in the synapse configuration but I can not use them for example in chaining scenarios, and I can use dynamic sequences in chaining scenarios but I cannot enable their statistics.

This is due to in the Send Mediator I can only  specified dynamic endpoints or sequences that exist in the registry, not in the synapse configuration.

What can I do to make my scenario work?

In the same scenario with a proxy service that implement a service chaining I can see the right response when I consume the service using SOAPUI but in BAM 2.0.1 appear as fail all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable statistics for dynamic endpoints and dynamic sequences by this way:
 1. Go to the registry resource,
    eg:- /_system/config/Hello
 2. Content -> Edit as text 
 3. Add statistics="enable" to address element
    [image]

Then if you have used that endpoint, statistics will be fired to BAM and you can see those if the Mediation statistics toolbox is installed.

Comment: thanks, it works. Of course, it would be more easy if I can put this option during sequence or endpoint creation.

Answer (score 1):

I have carried out a test on a Chaining service in WSO2 ESB and monitored it through the WSO2 BAM 2.0.1. It seems to work fine and did not encounter any statistics mismatch. The statistics matched with esb invocations.

ESB Statistics:
[image]

BAM Mediation Stats:
[image]

Comment: Can you see the statistic of dynamic endpoint and dynamic sequences in BAM?? In my scenario i can see the proxy service statistic but not of dynamic endpoints and sequences.